# How to set the element.style.left and element.style.top

Tags: javascript, styles

all

Accroding to the definition of the element.style.left below

- For absolutely positioned elements, the left property sets the left
  edge of an element to a unit to the left/right of the left edge of
  its containing element.
- For relatively positioned elements, the left property sets the left
  edge of an element to a unit to the left/right to its normal
  position.

If I want set my element to a special place, I should check the positioned attribute first, is it right?

Who can provide some code pieces to help me find out how to set the attributes correct correctly.

Thanks.

Comment: Show us what you tried so far!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is

Assume cssClass is class in styelsheet

```
cssClass{ 

position: absolute;
left:5px;
top:50px;
}
```

Or

```
<element style="position: absolute;left:5px;top:50px;" />
```